# Django Graphene not handling errors

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a GraphQL system associated with a Django app that seems to be working fine, except that it's completely ignoring errors in mutations.  That is, if the mutation executes with no errors, everything behaves as expected.  But if I raise an exception on the first line of the mutation, I don't get any indication of the error -- nothing in the app logs, and the graphQL response is just a json will null contents, e.g.:

```
{
    "data": {
        "exampleMutation": {
            "mutationResponseSchema": null
        }
    }
}
```

Even if I wrap the django pieces (e.g. trying to get a filterset) in a try: except:, the behavior is the same as if I raise the exception.  IOW, an exception being thrown (even if it's handled) seems to trigger an empty response being sent.

I am at a total loss for where these exceptions are going -- it seems that the behavior on encountering an exception is to ignore it and just return a null JSON.

Furthermore, I have an app with the same basic layout but built off an older image of Python (3.8 vs. this one at 3.11, so the django/graphene versions and related dependencies are newer).  The old app handled exceptions as usual and would return messages via the endpoints when raised using Django/Graphene classes with the same structure as the one I'm having the problem with.

I don't know if something changed in graphene's error handling, but I can't seem to find a clear answer to that.

For example, if I write the following mutation:

```
class ExampleMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
       fail_here = graphene.String()

    some_schema = graphene.Field(SomeSchema)

   @authorized
   def mutate(root, info, user, **kwargs):
       # could also just raise Exception('automatic exception') here and get same behavior.
       if kwargs.get('fail_here') == 'yes':
           raise Exception('text') # Doesn't seem to matter what exception is raised
       else:
           django_model = SomeSchemaModel.objects.first()
           return ExampleMutation(some_schema=django_model)
```

The response to e.g.

```
mutation exampleMutation($failHere: String){
    exampleMutation(
        failHere: $failHere,
    ) {
        someSchema
        {
            field1
            field2
        }
    }
}
```

is valid and behaves as expected if the mutation is called with e.g. {"failHere": "No"}.  Ergo, the structure of the graphQL/Django stuff is not the problem.

The problem is that when the endpoint is called with {"failHere": "yes"} (or if I just raise an error on the first line of the mutation), the response is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "exampleMutation": {
            "someSchema": null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The above might be a bug, I posted to github.  But in case this comes up for someone else, this is the workaround that got things working:

In django's settings (with appropriate SCHEMA for your app):

```
GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'core.graphql.index.schema',
    'MIDDLEWARE': ['graphene_django.debug.middleware.DjangoDebugMiddleware'],
}
```

I'm not certain of this, but I found from some searching that perhaps with newer versions of graphene-django, the DjangoDebugMiddleware middleware is required to send these exceptions in the JSON response.

In any case, the real problem is that the GraphQLView handler seems to need the middleware sent not as a list (as the settings shown above require), but instead as *double* list, which can be achieved by overriding the instantiation like this:

```
from graphene_django.views import GraphQLView, graphene_settings


class GQLView(GraphQLView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'middleware':[graphene_settings.MIDDLEWARE]}) #note the extra list level
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then in urls.py you'd have something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Graphql
    (r'graphql', GQLView.as_view())
]
```